# Why does my total session (aggregated using EXTRACT MONTH) is less than total session if I broke down by the date?

Tags: session, google-bigquery

I'm trying to generate my total session by month. I've tried using two different ways.

1. I'm using `date` field for the first column
2. I'm using `month` field that is extracted from `date` field using `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month`

I have tried using below code for the `1st` one:

```
with 
session1 as(
  select date,
  session_id
  from table
  where date >= '2019-05-20' AND date <= '2019-05-21')

SELECT date_key, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS sessions from session1
GROUP BY 1
```

For the `2nd` one I tried using this code:

```
with 
session1 as(
  select date,
  session_id
  from table
  where date >= '2019-05-20' AND date <= '2019-05-21')

SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_key) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS sessions from session1
GROUP BY 1
```

***For the result, I got the output as per below:***

1. 20 May: 1,548 Sessions; 21 May: 1,471 Sessions; ***Total: 3,019***
2. ***May: 2,905***

So, there's 114 session discrepancy and I'd like to know why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity sake - let's say there is only one session during two consecutive days. So if you will count by day and then sum result - you will get 2 sessions, while if you will count distinct sessions for whole two days - you will get just 1 session

Hope this shows you the reason why - you are counting some sessions twice on different days - maybe when they go over end of one and start of next day

Answer (score 0):

The following query should show you which sessions_ids occur on both dates.

```
select session_id, count(distinct date) as num_dates
from table
  where date >= '2019-05-20' AND date <= '2019-05-21'
group by 1
having num_dates > 1
```

This is either a data processing issue, or your session definition is allowed to span multiple days.  [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en), for example, traditionally ends a session and begins a new session at midnight.  Other sessionization schemes might not impose this restriction.